# Session state provider for Azure Managed Cache Service does not persist session objects

Tags: asp.net, session, caching, azure

I'm attempting to implement Azure Managed Cache Service with a Session State provider to my solution. Currently I am setting a Session variable, only to retrieve it after a postback and it's null. I can successfully persist objects to the cache using a DataCache object just fine, which tells me that my data cache settings are configured correctly in the Web.config, although my session state config settings might need fine tuning.

Relevant Web.config:

```
<sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="AFCacheSessionStateProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="AFCacheSessionStateProvider" type="Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache.DistributedCacheSessionStateStoreProvider, Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache" cacheName="default" dataCacheClientName="default" applicationName="AFCacheSessionState" />
  </providers>
</sessionState>
<dataCacheClients>
  <dataCacheClient name="default">
   <autoDiscover isEnabled="true" identifier="myEndpoint" />
   <securityProperties mode="Message" sslEnabled="true">
    <messageSecurity authorizationInfo="myKey" />
  </securityProperties>
</dataCacheClient>
```

UPDATE: I reinstalled Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Caching through the package manager console (rather than through the GUI), which produced a lot of exceptions that I did not see through GUI installation.

```
 PM> Install-Package Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Caching -Version 2.3.1
Installing 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Caching 2.3.1.0'.

You are downloading Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Caching from Microsoft, the license agreement to which is available at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=306250. Check the package for additional dependencies, which may come with their own license agreement(s). Your use of the package and dependencies constitutes your acceptance of their license agreements. If you do not accept the license agreement(s), then delete the relevant components from your device.

Successfully installed 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Caching 2.3.1.0'.
Adding 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Caching 2.3.1.0' to GPS-MVC.
Successfully added 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Caching 2.3.1.0' to GPS-MVC.

Exception calling "Item" with "1" argument(s): "InvalidParameter
Parameter name: index"
At C:\Users\eric.s\Source\Workspaces\packages\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Caching.2.3.1.0\tools\install.ps1:244 char:96
+ $csdefFiles = $ccProject.ProjectItems | where { $_.Properties -ne $null -and $_.Properties.Item <<<< ('BuildAction') -ne $null -and $_.Properties.Item('BuildAction').Value -eq 'ServiceDefinition' }
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

Exception calling "Item" with "1" argument(s): "InvalidParameter
Parameter name: index"
At C:\Users\eric.s\Source\Workspaces\packages\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Caching.2.3.1.0\tools\install.ps1:244 char:96
+ $csdefFiles = $ccProject.ProjectItems | where { $_.Properties -ne $null -and $_.Properties.Item <<<< ('BuildAction') -ne $null -and $_.Properties.Item('BuildAction').Value -eq 'ServiceDefinition' }
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

Exception calling "Item" with "1" argument(s): "InvalidParameter
Parameter name: index"
At C:\Users\eric.s\Source\Workspaces\packages\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Caching.2.3.1.0\tools\install.ps1:343 char:96
+ $cscfgFiles = $ccProject.ProjectItems | where { $_.Properties -ne $null -and $_.Properties.Item <<<< ('BuildAction') -ne $null -and $_.Properties.Item('BuildAction').Value -eq 'ServiceConfiguration'
 }
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

Exception calling "Item" with "1" argument(s): "InvalidParameter
Parameter name: index"
At C:\Users\eric.s\Source\Workspaces\packages\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Caching.2.3.1.0\tools\install.ps1:343 char:96
+ $cscfgFiles = $ccProject.ProjectItems | where { $_.Properties -ne $null -and $_.Properties.Item <<<< ('BuildAction') -ne $null -and $_.Properties.Item('BuildAction').Value -eq 'ServiceConfiguration'
 }
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "2" argument(s): "Access to the path 'C:\Users\eric.s\Source\Workspaces\GPS-MVC.Azure\ServiceDefinition.csdef' is denie
d."
At C:\Users\eric.s\Source\Workspaces\packages\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Caching.2.3.1.0\tools\install.ps1:90 char:27
+         $fileWriter = New-Object <<<<  System.Xml.XmlTextWriter($filepath, $null)
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand

Property 'Formatting' cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists and is settable.
At C:\Users\eric.s\Source\Workspaces\packages\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Caching.2.3.1.0\tools\install.ps1:91 char:15
+         $fileWriter. <<<< Formatting = [System.Xml.Formatting]::Indented
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Formatting:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound

Property 'Indentation' cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists and is settable.
At C:\Users\eric.s\Source\Workspaces\packages\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Caching.2.3.1.0\tools\install.ps1:92 char:15
+         $fileWriter. <<<< Indentation = 4
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Indentation:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound

Property 'IndentChar' cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists and is settable.
At C:\Users\eric.s\Source\Workspaces\packages\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Caching.2.3.1.0\tools\install.ps1:93 char:15
+         $fileWriter. <<<< IndentChar = ' '
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (IndentChar:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\eric.s\Source\Workspaces\packages\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Caching.2.3.1.0\tools\install.ps1:94 char:20
+         $fileWriter.Flush <<<< () 
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Flush:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Multiple ambiguous overloads found for "Save" and the argument count: "1".
At C:\Users\eric.s\Source\Workspaces\packages\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Caching.2.3.1.0\tools\install.ps1:403 char:15
+ $csdefXml.Save <<<< ($csdefWriter)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\eric.s\Source\Workspaces\packages\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Caching.2.3.1.0\tools\install.ps1:404 char:19
+ $csdefWriter.Close <<<< ()
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Close:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "2" argument(s): "Access to the path 'C:\Users\eric.s\Source\Workspaces\GPS-MVC.Azure\ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg'
 is denied."
At C:\Users\eric.s\Source\Workspaces\packages\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Caching.2.3.1.0\tools\install.ps1:90 char:27
+         $fileWriter = New-Object <<<<  System.Xml.XmlTextWriter($filepath, $null)
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand

Property 'Formatting' cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists and is settable.
At C:\Users\eric.s\Source\Workspaces\packages\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Caching.2.3.1.0\tools\install.ps1:91 char:15
+         $fileWriter. <<<< Formatting = [System.Xml.Formatting]::Indented
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Formatting:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound

Property 'Indentation' cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists and is settable.
At C:\Users\eric.s\Source\Workspaces\packages\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Caching.2.3.1.0\tools\install.ps1:92 char:15
+         $fileWriter. <<<< Indentation = 4
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Indentation:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound

Property 'IndentChar' cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists and is settable.
At C:\Users\eric.s\Source\Workspaces\packages\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Caching.2.3.1.0\tools\install.ps1:93 char:15
+         $fileWriter. <<<< IndentChar = ' '
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (IndentChar:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\eric.s\Source\Workspaces\packages\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Caching.2.3.1.0\tools\install.ps1:94 char:20
+         $fileWriter.Flush <<<< () 
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Flush:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Multiple ambiguous overloads found for "Save" and the argument count: "1".
At C:\Users\eric.s\Source\Workspaces\packages\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Caching.2.3.1.0\tools\install.ps1:409 char:16
+     $cscfgXml.Save <<<< ($cscfgWriter)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\eric.s\Source\Workspaces\packages\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Caching.2.3.1.0\tools\install.ps1:410 char:20
+     $cscfgWriter.Close <<<< ()
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Close:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "2" argument(s): "Access to the path 'C:\Users\eric.s\Source\Workspaces\GPS-MVC.Azure\ServiceConfiguration.Local.cscfg'
 is denied."
At C:\Users\eric.s\Source\Workspaces\packages\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Caching.2.3.1.0\tools\install.ps1:90 char:27
+         $fileWriter = New-Object <<<<  System.Xml.XmlTextWriter($filepath, $null)
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand

Property 'Formatting' cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists and is settable.
At C:\Users\eric.s\Source\Workspaces\packages\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Caching.2.3.1.0\tools\install.ps1:91 char:15
+         $fileWriter. <<<< Formatting = [System.Xml.Formatting]::Indented
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Formatting:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound

Property 'Indentation' cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists and is settable.
At C:\Users\eric.s\Source\Workspaces\packages\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Caching.2.3.1.0\tools\install.ps1:92 char:15
+         $fileWriter. <<<< Indentation = 4
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Indentation:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound

Property 'IndentChar' cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists and is settable.
At C:\Users\eric.s\Source\Workspaces\packages\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Caching.2.3.1.0\tools\install.ps1:93 char:15
+         $fileWriter. <<<< IndentChar = ' '
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (IndentChar:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\eric.s\Source\Workspaces\packages\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Caching.2.3.1.0\tools\install.ps1:94 char:20
+         $fileWriter.Flush <<<< () 
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Flush:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Multiple ambiguous overloads found for "Save" and the argument count: "1".
At C:\Users\eric.s\Source\Workspaces\packages\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Caching.2.3.1.0\tools\install.ps1:409 char:16
+     $cscfgXml.Save <<<< ($cscfgWriter)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\eric.s\Source\Workspaces\packages\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Caching.2.3.1.0\tools\install.ps1:410 char:20
+     $cscfgWriter.Close <<<< ()
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Close:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

While it states that the package successfully installed, that giant list of exceptions gives me pause. What went wrong with my installation, and how do I fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: Microsoft is recommending anyone looking to use distributed caching in Azure build their solutions on Redis which will be the long term distributed caching platform in Azure. I'd recommend you revisit your implementaiton to use Redis and leverage the session state provider Microsoft provides: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/05/12/announcing-asp-net-session-state-provider-for-redis-preview-release.aspx

Comment: @SimonW I appreciate the comment, and I'm okay with looking into that if I have to, but what I am trying to do is currently supported by Microsoft, no? So there should be a way to get my current implementation of the Session state provider working.

Comment: Your error is in the install Powershell script - the package downloaded OK but it hasn't been able to do any post download activities such as updating project configs. The errors suggest that perhaps the script was unable to read the project file(s) (access denied) which caused other logic to fail. Are you running Visual Studio as an admin user?

Comment: I am running as admin. Thanks for the information though. Is there a way to correct this manually? (i.e. update the project configs myself)

Comment: Actually, I take that back. I wasn't running as admin. And this has fixed it. @SimonW, thanks!